Keep recording the audio after closing the popup window of my extension
I can't make my extension keep recording the audio when the popup window is close or when i change the tab. I need to let this extension work at the background so user coul come back and stop recording of curent stream. I cannot make this work so please if You can let me know how can i keep recording audio even if the window of extension is closed it will be very helpful.
Thank You
**popup.js**

const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
const downloadButton = document.getElementById('download');
const pendingText = document.getElementById('pending');
const clientNameInput = document.getElementById('clientName');

let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];

// Request screen audio permissions only when the start button is clicked
async function getScreenAudioStream() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            // Check if permissions have been requested before
            chrome.storage.local.get(['screenAudioPermissionGranted'], async (result) => {
                if (result.screenAudioPermissionGranted) {
                    // If permission is already granted, proceed without requesting again
                    const displayStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                        audio: { echoCancellation: false, noiseSuppression: false }
                    });
                    resolve(displayStream);
                } else {
                    // Permission hasn't been granted before, request it now
                    const displayStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                        audio: { echoCancellation: false, noiseSuppression: false }
                    });

                    // After permission is granted, set the flag in storage to avoid future requests
                    chrome.storage.local.set({ screenAudioPermissionGranted: true });
                    resolve(displayStream);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Permission denied for audio capture. Please allow access to proceed.');
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}

// Check recording status when popup is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['isRecording'], async (result) => {
        if (result.isRecording) {
            // Update UI to show stop button
            clientNameInput.style.display = "none";
            startButton.style.display = "none";
            stopButton.style.display = "block";
            pendingText.style.display = "block";
            pendingText.innerText = "Recording in progress...";

            // Reattach MediaRecorder if popup is reopened
            const stream = await getScreenAudioStream();
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => audioChunks.push(e.data);
            mediaRecorder.start();
        }
    });
});

// Start Recording
startButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    try {
        const clientName = clientNameInput.value.trim();

        if (!clientName) {
            alert("Please enter a client name before starting the recording.");
            return;
        }

        // Save recording state
        chrome.storage.local.set({ isRecording: true });

        // Update UI
        clientNameInput.style.display = "none";
        startButton.style.display = "none";
        stopButton.style.display = "block";
        pendingText.style.display = "block";
        pendingText.innerText = "Recording started...";

        audioChunks = [];

        // Request screen audio permission if it's the first time
        const stream = await getScreenAudioStream();
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => audioChunks.push(e.data);

        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error starting recording:", err);
    }
});

// Stop Recording
stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (mediaRecorder) {
        mediaRecorder.stop();

        // Clear recording state
        chrome.storage.local.set({ isRecording: false });

        pendingText.style.display = "block";
        pendingText.innerText = "Pending... Please wait.";
        stopButton.style.display = "none";

        mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
            try {
                const webmBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });

                // Convert WebM to WAV
                const wavBlob = await convertWebMToWav(webmBlob);

                // Upload file to backend with client name
                const clientName = clientNameInput.value.trim();
                if (!clientName) {
                    pendingText.innerText = "Error: Client name missing.";
                    return;
                }

                pendingText.innerText = "Uploading... Please wait.";
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('audio', wavBlob, 'recorded-audio.wav');
                formData.append('clientName', clientName);

                await fetch('http://myserver/uploads', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                });

                // Trigger summarization
                pendingText.innerText = "Processing summary... Please wait.";
                const summaryResponse = await fetch('http://myserver/summarize', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ clientName })
                });

                const summaryData = await summaryResponse.json();
                if (summaryData.error) {
                    pendingText.innerText = `Error: ${summaryData.error}`;
                } else {
                    pendingText.innerText = `Summary Ready!`;
                    downloadButton.style.display = "block";
                }
            } catch (err) {
                pendingText.innerText = "Error during processing.";
                console.error("Error:", err);
            }
        };
    }
});

// Download Summary
downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const clientName = clientNameInput.value.trim();
    if (!clientName) {
        alert("Error: Client name missing.");
        return;
    }

    fetch(`http://myserver/download_summary?clientName=${encodeURIComponent(clientName)}`)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.download = `${clientName}_summary.txt`;
            link.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error("Error downloading summary:", err));
});

// Convert WebM to WAV format
function convertWebMToWav(webmBlob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = async () => {
            try {
                const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
                const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
                const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);

                const wavData = encodeWav(audioBuffer);
                const wavBlob = new Blob([wavData], { type: 'audio/wav' });
                resolve(wavBlob);
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(webmBlob);
    });
}

// Encode audio buffer to WAV
function encodeWav(audioBuffer) {
    const numChannels = audioBuffer.numberOfChannels;
    const sampleRate = audioBuffer.sampleRate;
    const samples = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    const bufferLength = samples.length;

    const header = new ArrayBuffer(44);
    const dataView = new DataView(header);
    dataView.setUint32(0, 0x46464952, true); // "RIFF"
    dataView.setUint32(4, 36 + bufferLength * 2, true);
    dataView.setUint32(8, 0x45564157, true); // "WAVE"
    dataView.setUint32(12, 0x20746d66, true); // "fmt "
    dataView.setUint32(16, 16, true);
    dataView.setUint16(20, 1, true);
    dataView.setUint16(22, numChannels, true);
    dataView.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
    dataView.setUint32(28, sampleRate * numChannels * 2, true);
    dataView.setUint16(32, numChannels * 2, true);
    dataView.setUint16(34, 16, true);
    dataView.setUint32(36, 0x61746164, true); // "data"
    dataView.setUint32(40, bufferLength * 2, true);

    const wavData = new Uint8Array(header.byteLength + bufferLength * 2);
    wavData.set(new Uint8Array(header), 0);

    for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        const sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, samples[i]));
        wavData[44 + i * 2] = (sample * 32767) & 0xFF;
        wavData[45 + i * 2] = ((sample * 32767) >> 8) & 0xFF;
    }
    return wavData;
}

**background.js**

let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];
let isRecording = false;
let clientName = "";

// Listen for messages from popup
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === "startRecording") {
        startRecording(message.clientName);
        sendResponse({ success: true });
    } else if (message.action === "stopRecording") {
        stopRecording();
        sendResponse({ success: true });
    } else if (message.action === "getStatus") {
        sendResponse({ isRecording });
    }
});

async function startRecording(name) {
    try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            audio: { echoCancellation: false, noiseSuppression: false }
        });

        clientName = name;
        audioChunks = [];
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => audioChunks.push(event.data);
        mediaRecorder.onstop = handleRecordingStop;

        mediaRecorder.start();
        isRecording = true;

        console.log("Recording started...");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error starting recording:", err);
    }
}

function stopRecording() {
    if (mediaRecorder && isRecording) {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        isRecording = false;
        console.log("Recording stopped...");
    }
}

async function handleRecordingStop() {
    try {
        const blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/webm" });

        // Upload to backend
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("audio", blob, `${clientName}-recording.webm`);

        await fetch("hhttp://myserver/uploads", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        });

        console.log("Recording uploaded successfully!");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error during upload:", err);
    }
}

I try to change the logic to background.js from popup but it does not work, the above code works but only when the popup window is open.

Use the offscreen document. You can create it in the popup.
